# How can I read lines from a file, only showing certain lines?

Tags: php, arrays, function, file-io

Here is part of my file:

```
nid: 4645867: Title
nid: 4645887: Metropolitan Afternoon
     oid: 4645888 | 35 x 38
     fid: 190035 | filepath: /var/storage/files/drupal/2e1a91af45d12ff9fb1b2231f88b7029.jpg
nid: 4645893: Fleurs du Matin II
     oid: 4645894 | 22 x 28
     fid: 190038 | filepath: /var/storage/files/drupal/d5e745715e21f649ff3fd8b3418581d9.jpg
nid: 4645913: Fleurs du Matin I
     oid: 4645914 | 22 x 28
     fid: 190045 | filepath: /var/storage/files/drupal/2f05f2c8e79997510d3f7f5a2cd28392.jpg
```

I only want to show lines that start with "nid".

Here is my code:

```
function tf_batch_view_deleted_items()
{

  $handle = fopen("/data/www/content/importTemp/delete_posters - ico.htm", "r");
  if ($handle) 
  {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) 
    {
      if (tf_common_contains($line, "nid"))
      {
        echo $line;
      }
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo "error opening the file.";
  } 
  fclose($handle);
}

function tf_common_contains($haystack, $needle)
{
  $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);

  if ($pos === FALSE)
  {
    return FALSE;
  }
  else
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

EDIT: It appears that the file is all on one line.

Comment: strpos returns 0 if $haystack starts with $needle so you can just change your condition

Comment: why would I need to change my condition?

Comment: because you said: 'I only want to show lines that start with "nid".' This condition will return TRUE also when "nid" will be in the middle of line

Comment: if ($pos === 0) {
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE
}

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use regex will do:

```
function tf_batch_view_deleted_items()
{

$handle = file_gets_content("/data/www/content/importTemp/delete_posters - ico.htm");

if ($handle !== "") 
{
    preg_match_all('/^nid:.*$/m', $handle, $match);
    foreach($match[0] as $line){
        echo $line;
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "error opening the file.";
} 
}
```

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1a1473fae77454d0e0d5f09b6c305111eaa6ee6

Comment: This is the only answer here that won't match lines containing 'nid' but not starting with it.

Comment: This gives me my original output, with the extra lines

Comment: I tried your edit, still giving me the same results.

Comment: Let's try again with new edit. But I honestly don't see how it's printing every line

Comment: Still giving me the same results.

Answer (score 1):

#### One-liner..

```
<?php

function tf_batch_view_deleted_items()
{

$arr = array_filter(array_map(function($v){  if(stripos($v,'nid:')!==false){ return $v;}},file('/data/www/content/importTemp/delete_posters - ico.htm',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)));
print_r($arr);

}

 tf_batch_view_deleted_items(); //<====== Call like this !!!
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => nid: 4645867: Title
    [1] => nid: 4645887: Metropolitan Afternoon
    [4] => nid: 4645893: Fleurs du Matin II
    [7] => nid: 4645913: Fleurs du Matin I
)
```

Comment: I got an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Comment: It's working on my side.. Checked once again.. I always post tested code.. Are you sure ?

Comment: How would I put this in my function tf_batch_view_deleted_items()?

Comment: You should call that function like `tf_batch_view_deleted_items();` on your code ?

Comment: Yes that is how I call my function

Comment: @AllisonC This is because your PHP version would be < 5.3 and has no support for anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($pos === 0) {
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file("abx.txt");
foreach($lines as $line){
if(substr($line, 0, 2) == "nid") echo $line;
}
```

Comment: This gives me a blank file

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = trim($line);
        $prefix = substr($line,0,3);

        if(strcasecmp($prefix,'nid') == 0) {
            echo $line.'<br />';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Could not find file!';
} 
fclose($handle);
```

?>

Comment: This gives me my original output, with the extra lines

Answer (score 0):

After I converted the html file to a text file, my code worked. Thanks for all your help though.